# BS4 http request gives error when I edit URL in code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trigger warning: I'm a noob

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import colored

with open('ign.txt') as f:
    namesList = f.readlines()
    print("Accounts found: ", namesList)  # Opening file and reading it

for x in namesList:
    url = "https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/" + x  # Adding username from file to URL
    print(url)
    headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_gain_today").get_text()
    title2 = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_gain altcolor xp_tracker_pos").get_text()
    title3 = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_next").get_text()  # Finding right information on site

    print(colored("Exp gain today: " + title, 'green'))
    print(colored("Exp gain yesterday: " + title2, 'green'))
    print(colored(title3, 'green'))  # Printing data found
```

When I modify my URL `url = "https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/" + x`
I get the following error message

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Which should mean there is nothing found.

This is the output from the upper half of the code `Accounts found:  ['mausie\n', 'mr+stevieyh\n', 'Douwe\n', 'Henk\n']https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/mausie`

So the link I made is correct

When I don't try to modify the URL and do let's say `url = "https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/myusername"`

It gives no error. However I want to loop trough my file to check more then 1 username.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what `print(url)` gives?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/mausie

Wich should be the correct URL, that's why I am confused :D

Comment: That's the one that works. I meant to say ..Do you get the usernames printed out correctly from the file? Share one which doesn't work.

Comment: https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/Douwe  ..There is no data for this user. Nor for `mrstevieyh` this one. Thats why the error.

Comment: It's mr+stevieyh not mrstevieyh.

I removed the ones without data and still get the same error.

mausie & mr+stevieyh do have data.

Comment: The code works fine if you change the URL yourself, however when I use the file to edit the url I can errors.

This is what my text file looks like, https://gyazo.com/6a4c1116339af0013c678ebcf55e58e1

EDIT: ```f.read()``` Only reads 1 char for me not the complete line

@AbrarAhmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem. When you read from the text file...an extra `\n` for newline is being added to your URL. That is why requests returns a 404 page not found error. A good idea is to check by using `print(repr(url))` instead of `print(url)`. That will show you the extra `'\n` . To fix this we just do `url=url.rstrip()` and Voila..It works.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import colored

with open('Sample', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    namesList = f.readlines()
    print("Accounts found: ", namesList)  # Opening file and reading it

for x in namesList:
    url = "https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/" + x  # Adding username from file to URL     print(repr(url))
    print(repr(url))
    url = url.rstrip()
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_gain_today").text
    title2 = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_gain altcolor xp_tracker_pos").text
    title3 = soup.find(class_="xp_tracker_next").text  # Finding right information on site

    print(colored("Exp gain today: " + title, 'green'))
    print(colored("Exp gain yesterday: " + title2, 'green'))
    print(colored(title3, 'green'))  # Printing data found
```

Output:-

```
 Accounts found:  ['mausie\n', 'mr+stevieyh\n']
'https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/mausie\n'
Exp gain today: 233,508
Exp gain yesterday: 469,011
Last tracked: 1 minute agoNext track available: now
'https://oldschool.runeclan.com/user/mr+stevieyh\n'
Exp gain today: 129,203
Exp gain yesterday: 730,434
Last tracked: 1 minute agoNext track available: now
```

That extra `\n` was the problem all along.

Comment: Thank you much Abrar!!